# Get value of elements using XML::DOM

Tags: xml, perl

For the life of me I can't seem to figure this out.

I got the below sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Datafile>
    <Contract>
        <A>234</A>
        <B>234</B>
        <C>2fs4</C>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <A>234</A>
        <B>21</B>
        <C>2fs4</C>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <A>23V</A>
        <B>234</B>
        <e/>
        <C>2fs4</C>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <A>234</A>
        <B>234</B>
        <e/>
        <C>2fs4</C>
            <d>234</d>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <A>2343</A>
        <B>234</B>
        <e/>
        <C>2fs4</C>
            <d>3kv</d>
    </Contract>
</Datafile>
```

I want to get the element values for each tag: like the value of A, which would be 234,234,23V... and so on.

This is what I got so far:

```
use XML::DOM;

 my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
 my $doc = $parser->parsefile ("./sample.xml");

 my $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName ("Contract");

 my $n = $nodes->getLength;

 for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
 {
     my $node = $nodes->item ($i); #returns one of the Contracts's array hash

     #print $node->getValue . "\n";
     #print $node;   
     #print $node->toString . "\n";
     foreach $myelement ($node->getChildNodes){
        #print $myelement . "\n";
        #print $myelement->toString . "\n"; #prints to string each childnode
        #print $myelement->getNodeName() . "\n"; #prints the element tag itself
        print $myelement->getNodeValue() . "bla \n";#doesn't print a thing 
     } 

 }
```

As you can see the idea is pretty simple. getElementsByTagName will return me a list of Contract. Then I use a for loop to step through the list of Contract. Then in each Contract I get the child nodes, A, B,C etc. But then I am stuck. I tried several methods on XML::DOM on search.cpan.org and all I keep getting are the hashed stuff, not the actual text values.

I found an example that required xml::dom::lite, while it works on my laptop it doesn't work on my office computer since I don't have sudo to install xml::dom::lite. it only has xml::dom and xml::parser it seems.

Comment: Elements don't have a value. I believe you want the value of the element's child nodes of type text. The DOM provides `$ele->textContent` to conveniently obtain this. However, XML::DOM didn't implement this. Why don't you switch to XML::LibXML? It's basically XML::DOM, but crazy faster, and without all the missing bits.

Comment: work host doesn't have LibXML, and I don't have sudo.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? You don't need any special permissions to install a module, so your inability to "sudo" is meaningless.

Comment: sorry, let me rephrase, installation of additional modules is currently not possible due to lack of permission.

Comment: That's not true, unless you can't write to any directory.

Comment: well let me try a few things first, maybe am wrong

Comment: Anyway, you now know where to look for the text you want, so adieu!

Comment: I would also encourage you to switch to XML::LibXML. However it could be challenging to install without sudo (you'd need the libxml2 C library and development header files installed first as well as a compiler, linker and related build tools). I suggest at least asking someone with admin access to install the Perl XML::LibXML package from the OS repository (e.g.: libxml-libxml-perl on Debian). Then you could use my guide: [Perl XML::LibXML by Example](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/).